# How to install curl development dependencies Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ruby, development, curl, gems

Was trying to run `bundle install` for a Ruby on Rails project which required `gem curb`. Here's what happened:

```
gem install curb
Fetching curb-0.9.11.gem
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing curb:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/lance/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/curb-0.9.11/ext
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.4/bin/ruby -I /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20210120-31208-z4fk7m.rb extconf.rb
checking for curl-config... no
checking for -lcurl... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-curl-dir
    --without-curl-dir
    --with-curl-include
    --without-curl-include=${curl-dir}/include
    --with-curl-lib
    --without-curl-lib=${curl-dir}/lib
    --with-curllib
    --without-curllib
extconf.rb:18:in `<main>':   Can't find libcurl or curl/curl.h (RuntimeError)

  Try passing --with-curl-dir or --with-curl-lib and --with-curl-include
  options to extconf.

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /home/lance/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/curb-0.9.11/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Need to install the correct packages.  The error shows the problem in `curl.h` so
go to [http://packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=curl%2Fcurl.h) and search for `curl.h` which shows what needs to be installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libcurl4-nss-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Comment: See https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=curl%2Fcurl.h without guessing.

Comment: @N0rbert thanks! I updated my answer.